# How can I change the smileys in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I chat a lot in Facebook and like the appearance of their emoticons. I want to change it from the current one.

How can I get this appearance on my blog?

Can I add more emoticons to the list as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the instructions [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Smilies#How_Can_I_Have_Different_Smiley_Images_Appear.3F), you can upload new smiley images to be used in your /wp-includes/images/smilies folder.

Comment: Does this allow you to add new smilies ? Say I wanted to add [:putman:](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_t4OAkL5zAZE/ScRg8dHt82I/AAAAAAAAAMw/AaMzx6LIJPY/s400/human+head+facebook.jpg)

Comment: I believe this would allow you to add new smilies, although there may be other steps necessary.  Please consider voting for this answer if you think it's a good answer to your question.